# How to reverse sort a column on click using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple method of sorting the table column implemented but I can't figure out a way to alternate between reverse the sorting on click and back. Does anyone have any solutions to this issue? Below is a fiddle showing you what I mean.

```
<div ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="controller">

    <p>{{orderProperty}}</p>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Status<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'a'">^</a></th>
                <th>Ref<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'b'">^</a></th>
                <th>Service<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'c'">^</a></th>
                <th>Domain<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'd'">^</a></th>
                <th>Service Owner<a ng-click="orderProperty     = 'e'">^</a></th>
                <th>Stage<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'f'">^</a></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in projects | orderBy:orderProperty">
                    <td><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
                    <td>{{x.b}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.c}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.d}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.e}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.f}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/3nxykbhk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle the orderProperty by prefixing the column name with '-'.
Replace your table header with this code:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Status<a ng-click="setOrderProperty('a')">^</a></th>
        <th>Ref<a ng-click="setOrderProperty('b')">^</a></th>
        <th>Service<a ng-click="setOrderProperty('c')">^</a></th>
        <th>Domain<a ng-click="setOrderProperty('d')">^</a></th>
        <th>Service Owner<a ng-click="setOrderProperty('e')">^</a></th>
        <th>Stage<a ng-click="setOrderProperty('f')">^</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

... and add this function to your scope:

```
$scope.setOrderProperty = function(propertyName) {
    if ($scope.orderProperty === propertyName) {
        $scope.orderProperty = '-' + propertyName;
    } else if ($scope.orderProperty === '-' + propertyName) {
        $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
    } else {
        $scope.orderProperty = propertyName;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nxykbhk/1/

Comment: How I can sort data in decimal format. like  10.32,34.43.22.78

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the ordering by passing `true` as the 3rd part of the `orderBy` filter:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in projects | orderBy : orderProperty : true">
```

Comment: Ah, should have been more clear. What I mean to ask was how to alternate between reversed and normal sorting on click.

Answer (score 1):

**In the html**

change the `ng-click` to call a function

```
<tr>
    <th><a ng-click="sortProperty('a')">Status</a></th>
    <th><a ng-click="sortProperty('b')">Ref</a></th>
    <th><a ng-click="sortProperty('c')">Service</a></th>
    <th><a ng-click="sortProperty('d')">Domain</a></th>
    <th><a ng-click="sortProperty('e')">Service Owner</a></th>
    <th><a ng-click="sortProperty('f')">Stage</a></th>
</tr>
```

**In the Javascript:**

add a '+' to the orderProperty variable

`$scope.orderProperty = "+f";`

then add this function

```
$scope.sortProperty = function(column) {
    var currentColumn = $scope.orderProperty.slice(1);
    var currentDirection = $scope.orderProperty.slice(0, 1);
    var dir = '+';

    if (column === currentColumn) {
        dir = currentDirection === '+' ? '-' : '+';
    }
    $scope.orderProperty = dir + column;
};
```

Clicking on the column header will now toggle the sort

[see JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/garyh/Leemra65/)