# reverse order on second click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have table with orders and i want to sort them on click and reverse sort on second click.On first click sorting works fine  but on second click reverse sorting does not work.It throws parsing exception.Here is my code 
HTML

```
 <tr>
    <th><a href="#" ng-click="changeOrder('merchant.id');" ng-dblclick="forDoubleClick('merchant.id')"><abbr title="Merchant ID">M.I.</abbr></a></th>
    </tr>

     <tr dir-paginate="item in serverData | orderBy : orderBy | filter:filterData | itemsPerPage: itemPerPageValue"></tr>

    ...
```

my JS code

```
$scope.orderBy = 'value';

$scope.changeOrder = function(value) {
        $scope.orderBy = value;
    }

$scope.forDoubleClick = function(value)
    {
        $scope.orderBy = value + " : reverse ";
    }
```

Comment: get help from [this useful SO answres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074578/how-to-reverse-sort-a-column-on-click-using-angularjs)

Comment: thank you it is working fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need `$scope.forDoubleClick` function, I just added one more variable `$scope.currentOrder = 1;` which will decide the `Sort` order. i.e. if `%` or `remainder` equals `0` sort by `Ascending` order else by `Descending` order.

And increment `$scope.currentOrder` on each `click`

```
$scope.currentOrder = 1;
$scope.changeOrder = function(value) {
$scope.currentOrder++;
if($scope.currentOrder % 2 != 0)
    $scope.orderBy = '-' + value;
}else{
    $scope.orderBy = value;
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but reverse sorting was wrong, i think it works different for string and for int , but i dont know in the beggining which one will be my sorting objects (int or string) it must be working for both of them.

Comment: could you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
$scope.sortOrder = 'ASC';
$scope.changeOrder = function(value) {
    if($scope.sortOrder === 'ASC') {
        $scope.orderBy = value;
        $scope.sortOrder = 'DSC';
    } else {
        $scope.orderBy = value + " : reverse ";
        $scope.sortOrder = 'ASC';
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it occurs parse error. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=:&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=13&p3=merchant.id%20:%20reverse&p4=:%20reverse

Comment: i tried , same error

Comment: Can you remove single quote from  ng-click="changeOrder(merchant.id);" and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-click="changeOrder('merchant.id');"` put

`ng-click="changeOrder(merchant.id);"`same goes for `ng-dblclick`.

Comment: i tried it. did not work